# Calculate real width/height of html template

Tags: javascript, html

I have html template in js, like:

```
<div style="top: ...; height: .....>....</div>
```

How can i find actual width of this div after rendering?

I tried `window.getComputedStyle(myElement)`, it finds element but returns:

```
width: auto
height: null
```

How can i find real height/width?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

`var w = element.outerWidth;
var h = element.outerHeight;`

to calculate width and height including padding.

You can use `innerWidth` or `innerHeight` to calculate width and height without padding.

Comment: I'm adding element with angular.element(element[0]).append(html);, the i'm getting undefined with document.getElementById('my-popup').outerWidth

Answer (score 2):

Id your div

```
<div id="a_div" style="top: ...; height: .....>....</div>
```

And use javascript

```
var height = document.getElementById("a_div").style.height.replace("px","");
var width = document.getElementById("a_div").style.width.replace("px","");
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/D5LzD/)

Comment: Made it, but It returns ''

Comment: Yes it works, but i don't know exactly width, i can't set up fixed width as in your example.